# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'mat'

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

txt = open(filename)

header = txt.readline().split()
inputArray = map(float, txt.readline().split())
txt.close()

inputMat = np.mat(inputArray)
inputMat.reshape(int(header[0]), int(header[1]))
inputMat.shape()

#takes q2data as input
def lu(A):
    #Decomposes a nxn matrix A by PA=LU and returns L, U and P.
    n = len(A)
    L = [[0.0] * n for i in xrange(n)]
    U = [[0.0] * n for i in xrange(n)]

    #Creates the pivoting matrix for m.
    n = len(A)
    ID = [[float(i == j) for i in xrange(n)] for j in xrange(n)]
    for j in xrange(n):
        row = max(xrange(j, n), key=lambda i: abs(A[i][j]))
        if j != row:
            ID[j], ID[row] = ID[row], ID[j]
    p = ID

    #perform matrix multplication
    TA = zip(*A)
    A2 = [[sum(eP*ea for eP,ea in zip(P,a)) for a in TA] for P in p]

    for j in xrange(n):
        L[j, j] = 1.0
        for i in xrange(j+1):
            s1 = sum(U[k, j] * L[i, k] for k in xrange(i))
            U[i, j] = A2[i, j] - s1
        for i in xrange(j, n):
            s2 = sum(U[k, j] * L[i, k] for k in xrange(j))
            L[i, j] = (A2[i, j] - s2) / U[j, j]
    return (L, U, p)

print (lu(inputMat))
```

Saved as LUdecomp.py
Tried to run it in CMD as LUdecomp.py q1data.txt in C:\Python34
And gave the error:

```
C:\Python34>python LUdecomp.py q1data.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LUdecomp.py", line 12, in <module>
    inputMat = np.mat(inputArray)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'mat'
```

Comment: Did you name a file `numpy.py`? If so, Python thinks that's NumPy. Pick a different name.

Comment: Nope, don't have anything called numpy.py

Comment: Do `print np` and see what it says.

Comment: Unable to initialize device PRN

Comment: No, do `print np` in Python. (Or actually, `print(np)`, since you're on Python 3.)

Comment: <module 'numpy' (namespace)>

Answer (score 0):

Had numpy.whl installed incorrectly.